# Creating new Magento products leaves 'Use default value' unchecked

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1.6, simple-product, programmatically

I am creating configurable and simple products programmatically using the code

```
$websiteid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteID();              
$storeid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreID();                  

$configproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');                      
$configproduct                                                           
    ->setStoreId($storeid)                                               
    ->setWebsiteIds(array($websiteid))                                   
    ->setAttributeSetID(9)           
    ->setTypeId('configurable')                                          
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))                                     
    ->setSku($sku)                                                       
    ->setName($name)                                                     
    ->setStatus(2) //1: enabled, 2:disabled                              
    ->setTaxClassId(2)                           
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
    ->setPrice($price)                                                   
    ->setCost($cost)                                                     
    ->setStockData(array(                                                
            'is_in_stock' => 0                                           
        )                                                                
    );                                                                               
//This is the "size" attribute                           
$configproduct->getTypeInstance()                                        
    ->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(127));                            
$configurableAttributesData = $configproduct->getTypeInstance()          
    ->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();                                
$configproduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);                  
$configproduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

$configproduct->save();
```

for configurable products and

```
    $websiteid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteID();              
    $storeid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreID();                  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');                            
    $product                                                                 
        ->setStoreId($storeid)                                               
        ->setWebsiteIds(array($websiteid))                                   
        ->setAttributeSetID(9)                                               
        ->setTypeId('simple')                                                
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))                                     
        ->setSku($sku)                                                       
        ->setName($name)                                                     
        ->setStatus(2)                                                       
        ->setTaxClassId(2)                                                   
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
        ->setPrice($price)                                                   
        ->setCost($cost)                                                     
        ->setStockData(array(                                                
                'is_in_stock' => 0                                           
            )                                                                
        )                                                                    
        ->setClothesSize($size_id);                                           

    $product->save();
```

for simple products.

The desired outcome is that the products are added with the given information, and that all stores use the default values for all attributes. However, for all of the stores, the 'Use default value' for the 'Status' attribute is left unchecked, and for one of the stores, the "use default value" checkbox for the "name", "url key", and "visibility" attributes are also unchecked.

Can anyone help me achieve that desired behavior? I assume it has something to do with the StoreId perhaps, but don't know how I would change the above to make it do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I see you're doing

```
$websiteid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteID();              
$storeid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreID();
```

That's not working, it should be

```
$websiteid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId();              
$storeid = (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

If you want all stores to use the default values, you should set the Store ID to `(int) 0`, because that is the admin store. All store views should use the default values then.

Also, be aware that if you want to have the product added to all websites, you should get all website IDs, not just one. This can be done with:

```
$websiteIds = array();
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
    $websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
}
```